# Suspected: JIT deoptimization in Java caused our service sudden performance degradation

Tags: java, performance, jit, jfr

Our service runs on JDK17, which is a simple storage query service without complex logic.
Sometimes its rpc interface's TP9999 may experiences a surge (from tens of milliseconds to several seconds or even more than ten seconds), accompanied by 100% CPU utilization.

This situation often suddenly happens on the stable running machines, and after several seconds it will automatically recover.

**We have found something at the abnormal moments by JFR:**

1. There is always JIT deoptimization and recompilation occurring which
   were concentrated on JSON deserialization method(our main business
   logic is JSON deserialization).
2. Sometimes it is the C2 compiler thread that has excessive CPU
   usage, while at other times it is the business threads that consume
   a high amount of CPU.

I guess the JIT deoptimization may cause the interface's performance decreasing.
So what should I do for fixing or reducing this performance problem?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but you may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890873/why-does-java-just-in-time-compiler-continue-to-recompile-same-methods-and-make

Comment: Do you have a gc log? Are you actually using RPC?

Comment: @Erik I see the gc pause time is normal by JFR.Is the gc log necessary for solving the problem?  Our service don't request other services by RPC, but it will query redis.

Comment: When you use RPC, the GC is scheduled to run at regular intervals. The CPU surge you see might be indicative of the RPC gc run. The GC log will show you the gc behaviour over time. You should always have a gc log. 
You can log HotSpot compilation with ` -XX:+LogCompilation`
Are you being called by RPC or are you calling a RPC server?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just by removing the branch prediction logic of the OpenJDK:

```
src/hotspot/share/opto/parse2.cpp

//-----------------------------branch_prediction-------------------------------
float Parse::branch_prediction(float& cnt,
                               BoolTest::mask btest,
                               int target_bci,
                               Node* test) {

  return PROB_FAIR;
  //float prob = dynamic_branch_prediction(cnt, btest, test);
  // If prob is unknown, switch to static prediction
  ...
}
```